# How to get MAC address from ifconfig

Tags: networking, ifconfig

How can I get MAC address on my notebook? I know I must input `ifconfig`, but I don't see the line "HWaddr". 
This is my output:

```
$ sudo ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 28:d2:44:e8:30:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Локальная петля (Loopback))
        RX packets 346  bytes 25136 (25.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 346  bytes 25136 (25.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::14ad:7ca7:54ef:869a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 38:b1:db:c7:a5:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25121  bytes 28532799 (28.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19936  bytes 2836709 (2.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Where is MAC address here?

Answer (score 8):

Your mac address are being shown under `ether` lines.

```
ether 28:d2:44:e8:30:6a
```

and

```
ether 38:b1:db:c7:a5:27
```

---

You can even use `nmcli` to get your mac address:

```
nmcli device show enp3s0 | grep -i hw
```

or

```
nmcli device show wlp4s0 | grep -i hw
```

both outputs will be similar to:

```
GENERAL.HWADDR:      38:b1:db:c7:a5:27
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings.
Select Network.
Click on the settings next to your current connection (Wired or Wifi).
Then mac address will be available under the name Hardware address.
Or you can switch to the tab labelled Identity -  MAC Address will be specified there (Ubunutu 18.04)